# Watermark in Pdf using css or Rotativa (PDF generater)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, watermark, rotativa

I am using rotativa for generate PDF in MVC.

I want watermark in all pages of PDF but unfortunately I am not achieving this.

I have researched also for rotativa but can't find any proper solution for this. And then I have tried this using CSS.

I have tried this

**CSS**

```
   #background {
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            min-width: 100%;
            opacity: 0.5;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: transparent;
            padding-top:50%;
        }
        #bg-text {
            color: lightgrey;
            font-size: 120px;
            transform: rotate(300deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
            opacity: 0.9;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50);
            background-color: transparent;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="background">
            <p id="bg-text">Draft</p>
        </div>
```

It's works fine for first page of PDF. And I want this in all pages of PDF.
Please suggest me a proper solution for this problem of watermark.

Any solution will be appreciable using **CSS** or using **rotativa**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my problem by following

**Html**

```
<div class="watermark" style="background: url('../Images/watermark.png');"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .watermark {
            height: 95%;
            width: 90%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-repeat: repeat-y;
            z-index: 9999;
            opacity: 0.2;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<div class="watermark" style="font-family: Calibri; border-left: 1px solid lightgrey; border-right: 

        <style type="text/css">
            .watermark {
                background-image: url("../../Resources/Watermark/Draft5.png");
                background-repeat: repeat-y;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 100000;
            }
        </style>
```

Keep in mind that put  tag under body element otherwise it wont work when you are using rotativa